# How to find if IP is being used?

Tags: linux, bash, networking

I have following IP in a server

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
```

I need to know if those IP are being used or not?

I could find using lsof but it's too slow

```
for ip in ${server_ip_list[@]}; do
    lsof -i @$ip &>/dev/null && echo "$ip is used" || echo "$ip is unused"
done
```

Below command is faster but I need to specify port and protocol

```
true &>/dev/null </dev/tcp/192.168.1.1/80 && echo used || echo unused
```

I'm looking for a faster command using which I can determine if the IP is used regardless of protocol or port.

I'd appreciate if anyone could help with a solution or links where I can read about it.

Comment: Is writing an own program (e.g. in C) an option?

Comment: @Martin Rosenau, I'm using bash.

Comment: It looks like the only IP in use is IPv4. Your list has no IPv6 addresses.

Comment: @Ron Maupin, Yes, only for IPv4

Comment: There is your answer. The IP being used is IPv4. I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: @Ron Maupin, There are several IPv4 addresses in the server, I need to find which IP are being used(by any service). For example: is an IP 192.168.1.1 is used by a process, I can find it using `lsof @192.168.1.1` but it takes long time. I need a better way to find used and unused IP.

Comment: Yes, there are several IP addresses in the server, but there is only one IP. Are you asking about IPs or IP addresses, because your question is asking about the IP (Internet Protocol)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157634/discussion-between-derp-and-ron-maupin).

Comment: What means "used" ? You could check netstat if something is listening on a port of that address

Comment: @ Marged, I have tried netstat too, but this is slow too.
Besides, there's no fixed port, it can any port from 0-65535.

Comment: @ Marged, used means this IP is being used by a service in the server, for example mail.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use command `ping` to check if specific ip is being used (not disable `ICMP` in firewall). If you think `for` or `while` loop operation is too slow, you could try to use command `parallel` to execute command simultaneously.

Code sample like

```
ip_check(){
    ip="$1"
    ping -c 1 -W 1 "$ip" &> /dev/null
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo 'used'
    else
        echo 'unused'
    fi
}

export -f ip_check

cat ip_file.txt | parallel -k -j 0 ip_check 2> /dev/null
```